# How to find the code difference between two Java programming fast?

Tags: java

Let's say I have two Java projects (eclipse) contain multiple packages and files. They have the same files but one of its code is modified and changed in multiple locations. And I want to find all the code difference in the files between these two projects.

Is there any software or ways to do it quickly?

Comment: A version control system is the "easiest' way.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this using one of the diff programs that can compare directories recursively.  I recommend [Meld](http://meldmerge.org) and [KDiff3](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: It works like a charm, thank you.